# How should I approach my boss about a raise/promotion?

Tags: promotion

What is the best manner to approach a supervisor and request a raise or promotion?

As a web developer, it's not really easy to quantify performance standards on any type of metrics either.

Comment: I suggest this question be split up. I've got some advice for you, but the answer is different for a raise & promotion.

Comment: I remember writing [an answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1832/316) to this kind of a question a while back that you may be interested in. I'm not going to vote this as a duplicate though because the details of the question and the answers given there are different than your situation.

Comment: related: [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First and foremost, be honest with yourself. I would say evaluate yourself and determine your worth in the company. If you feel that you need a raise, be honest with your employer. Explain to them what you are looking for (raise or promotion) and I would not expect to get an answer right away. Just drop a bug in their ear and if they request to think about it for a week or two, let them. If this time goes by and you still do not hear anything from them, schedule a meeting with them and bring it up again. Go into the meeting knowing what you would like to get and what you are willing to go with for now.

Answer (score 7):

One thing that could be convincing would be assembling a list of new skills you've acquired since you were hired (or since your last raise/promotion).  I should be easier for your boss to consider the possibility of a raise or promotion when it's presented as "You started out paying $X for someone who could do A, B and C, but now you actually have someone who can do A, B, C, D and E."

A list of specific accomplishments, if they're above average compared to your coworkers, would definitely help as well. I would think of it somewhat like preparing a resume.

Comment: I don't think so, skills are something expected. The real value of him is his work and quality of it. Skills not used are not importante.