# Asking about a salary increase to go along with a title change

Tags: salary, promotion, politics, compensation, title

I've been told that I will be receiving a title change in a few months which entails a lot more responsibility. The promotion is technically a management level position, while I'm currently not a manager of anyone. There was no mention of a salary increase that will go along with the title change (which is not to say that there won't be one). Though, I know that my sister went through receiving a title change with added responsibility and they never gave her an increase for it. I'd like to make sure that it doesn't happen to me, just in case.

So, my question is - How and when should I ask my boss if my title change comes with a salary increase?

Comment: It's a reasonable question. Just ask. Don't be surprised if the response is "No, but it removes a possible barrier to giving you a raise in the future."

Comment: Ask point blank. You have a right to know, and you'll know anyway when you get your first paycheck for the new position.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I approach my boss about a raise/promotion?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/207/how-should-i-approach-my-boss-about-a-raise-promotion)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So, my question is - How and when should I ask my boss if my title
>   change comes with a salary increase?

You should have asked about a raise when you were informed of your promotion.

Since that apparently didn't happen, and since you are still a few months away from this change, you should simply bring it up in your weekly one-on-one meeting with your boss (assuming you have one).

If you don't regularly meet, ask for a time when you can meet.

Discuss more of the specifics of your new position - the duties and responsibilities, exactly when it should take effect, how it will be announced to the rest of the team, etc.

Then just ask if you can expect a raise along with the promotion.

No need to be shy about it.

You might learn that you will get a raise as soon as the promotion takes effect, and how much the raise will be. You might learn that you won't get a raise. Or you might learn that a raise will follow somewhere down the road.

Comment: It was a hard lesson for me to learn (women are often taught culturally not to ask for things as that is pushy), but "them as don't ask, don't get" is often true.

Comment: +1 employers love to give promotions without money, especially if you're going to keep your mouth shut and take it.