# Asking for a promotion after 1.5 years

Tags: promotion

I started my Job about a year ago and in the space of one year, I have demonstrated my abilities in the organisation, I have also completed a designation. all my colleagues and leadership team are well aware of my performance. I was thinking of asking for a promotion during my yearly review by the end of the year, this isn't only about the money, I honestly believe I am ready for position I am asking to be promoted to. I am worried if 1.5 years is too soon to ask for a promotion.

Comment: It isn't about you, it is about the company. If you can make a case that they will be better off with you promoted, you have a fighting chance. Otherwise look for a promotion elsewhere, in my experience changing jobs is usually easier to get promoted or get a salary bump.

Comment: We can't help you decide what to do because the situation is unique to you. We don't know your company, boss, the culture of the company, etc. My advice would be to go ahead and ask .. the worst that can happen is that you would be declined. If you're getting bent out of shape about whether you deserve the promotion then maybe you're not ready for more responsibility. If instead you demonstrate confidence, you stand a good chance to get what you're gunning for. Strangers on the internet can't help you.

Comment: Also, you don't *ask* for a promotion, you have a discussion with your boss, state your intentions (you want to be promoted), and ask them what you need to do to make that happen. Outside of small(er) companies, promotions very rarely happen on the spot. There is almost always a (sometimes lengthy) period of laying groundwork beforehand.

Comment: Related - [How should I approach my boss about a raise/promotion?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/207/how-should-i-approach-my-boss-about-a-raise-promotion)

Answer (score 3):

It's never too soon. As soon as you prove you're worth the investment, it's a good time to ask.

> I have demonstrated my abilities in the organisation, I have also completed a designation. all my colleagues and leadership team are well aware of my performance

Sounds like you've already done that. Small nitpick, just because your abilities are great doesn't mean they bring value to the company, but that's just me being pedantic. Bring your *I'm awesome<sup>1</sup>* file with you, and good luck

---

<sup>1</sup> *Every time you do something great, you put it in this file. When it's time for review, you pull it out to show what you've achieved*

Comment: Awesome file is a really great idea! I'm gonna start doing this.

Comment: Just want to add: If your abilities are worth more than the value you bring to the company, you are currently overqualified and should look for another job!

Comment: Just make sure the awesomeness is work-related. "My application of hair gel today was off the charts" is probably not helpful to your cause.  :D

Answer (score 2):

It's a little soon.. but I wouldn't say it was *too* soon. Less than a year would be pushing it a little, less than six months would likely be viewed as  presumptuous and less than three months would probably see you laughed out of your manager's office, 18 months is probably long enough for you to have proven your worth and to have repaid the investment in time, effort and possibly money that the company expended in recruiting you for your original position.

The best approach is to line up some arguments as to not only why you are capable/qualified to perform the role you are aiming for but most importantly why the company would benefit more from having you in the new position rather than your current one. If your current role has any transferable skills or knowledge that would help in the new one and you have any examples of achievements or feedback to support you having that skills/knowledge then use these to support your position.

It's also a good idea to show awareness of what would be involved in recruiting someone external for both positions - if [old role] is really easy to recruit for but people who can do [new role] are hard to find then this works in your favor, if the reverse is the case then having some suggestions for how you could help with any transition is a good way to show that you're taking the company's needs into account.

Comment: I asked for a raise of 20% after 6 month with a new employer. Got it without much discussion. If you are worth more than you are getting, and everyone knows it, it is never to early.

Comment: @Daniel the timescales I gave in my answer are more of a guideline for anything else. Proving you're worth it (for either a promotion or a raise) is indeed key and the shorter the timespan the less likely it is that you will have been able to effectively demonstrate that. Turn up on your first day and cure cancer/invent cold fusion before lunch? Yeah you can probably ask for a raise that afternoon.

Comment: @Daniel if you're worth significantly more than you're getting, 90% of the time you're better off looking for a new job where you'll actually get what you're worth than it is to try and negotiate raises and promotions that will get you there.

Comment: @Cronax: That is not my experience. It may be easier for some, to negotiate in a setting where you "have nothing to loose". On the other hand if you apply elsewhere they really can´t know what you are worth so you are almost guaranteed to get either under- or overestimated. beeing overpaid may sound good but really isn´t if you can´t deliver ...

Comment: @Daniel If you feel you're worth X, you can simply ask for X at your new job. Convincing your current employer to pay you X instead of something far less than X is a lot harder. If the other company underestimates your worth, find a different company. If the other company overestimates your worth, they will feel like X is a bargain and will easily agree to it. Asking for X at your current company usually makes them feel like you're trying to pressure you into giving you X 'or else you'll leave'. Far from a setting where you have nothing to loose.

Comment: I don't agree that 1.5 yrs is too soon- it depends on the role and the candidate. If the candidate has outgrown a role, it doesn't make sense for them to be in an environment that's not stimulating or stagnant. If you're doing work that doesn't interest you, you're going to get burned out, and that's not good for you or the company.

Comment: @cocanut Not sure if your comment was intended for me or whether I've got the wrong end of the stick here but I'm not saying that 1.5 years is too soon.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts in this:

1. Promotion:

If you take out the money, this is asking for more responsibility. From a employers perspective the this should be a good thing. Provided you have an accurate picture of yourself and can handle what you asked for, you can always do this.

There are some circumstances that may prevent your superiors to give you that responsibility right now despite thinking you could handle it. If that is the case, be patient and make the discussion about where you want to get to, once there is room for promotion. 
Letting your bosses know you are ready and willing for more responsibility is one step towards actually getting it.

2. Raise:

Ideally, you should get what your services are worth. Now this value is hard to estimate, but the bottom line is: what somebody else would pay for you, if you changed job´s.

As a rule of thumb, you can and should renegotiate this about once a year, or whenever your work changes significantly.

How much you are really paid depends largely on your ability to negotiate and if you are in the right position (not over-qualified). So before going into any such discussion,  do your homework and really know your worth and your options, should you not reach a common understanding of it. After all, a negotiation you can´t walk away from is not a negotiation.