# How can I ask for a raise from the new CFO?

Tags: salary, performance-reviews, new-hires

So the CFO at our company retired, and he was my direct boss. I've been commended for my work at all echelons of the company and have been lauded for my skills; I am the de facto subject matter expert for all things in relation to my position (and in some cases not related). I am up for my annual Performance Review, and the retiring CFO didn't leave any sort of residual information for the new CFO on employee performance.

The brand new CFO (1 month) is approachable, laid back, and has extensive experience in C-suite positions. From the work I've shown him and from his comments on the work I've done along with the communication I've given him, he seems to have the same impression of my current skills, responsibilities, and accomplishments. My problem is he doesn't have much first hand experience with my reports and his sample size is dismally small. The CEO and COO have both expressed admiration for the work I've given them, but delegate heavily to those under them (they're retiring soon too), so I am bounced back to the new CFO for this to happen.

I'd like to ask for a performance review and a raise of him, but without the background, the only information I could see positively for me would all come second-hand.

**How can I ask my brand new manager for a Performance Review and a raise while minimizing any recency bias?**

Comment: *"the retiring CFO didn't leave any sort of residual information for the new CFO on employee performance. "* - So, how did the former CFO did the review? Are there documents or logs he could analyze that may help determine if a raise is in place, or did he determined that solely by what he perceived?

Comment: Related - https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/207/how-should-i-approach-my-boss-about-a-raise-promotion

Comment: Related - https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CFO is aware that he doesn't have much personal experience with you. Just show him what you can and ask for a raise. He will find other avenues ranging from speaking to the CEO to contacting your previous CFO, that's his job.

Performance reviews are rarely just talking to the reviewee.